Are There U.S. Laws or Presidential Actions That Cannot Be Overturned by Successor Presidents?
In U.S. history, presidents have often enacted laws or established policies that were intended to have long-term effects, sometimes beyond their own term in office. However, it seems that successor presidents frequently overturn or reverse their predecessor's actions.
For example:

President Obama enacted the Clean Power Plan to reduce carbon emissions, which President Trump later reversed.
President Trump withdrew the U.S. from the Paris Climate Agreement, which President Biden then rejoined upon taking office.
Similarly, President Reagan had policies that were significantly altered or reversed by the incoming Bush and Clinton administrations.

Given these examples, I’m curious if there are certain types of laws or policies that a new president cannot easily reverse. Specifically:
Are there any laws or policies enacted by one president that are protected from being overturned by the next administration?

How do you define protected? Impossible to repeal? Only able to be repealed after some time has passed?

And is this just about Presidential action, or does this also apply to stuff in which congress is involved?

What do you mean by the president overturning a law? All laws and repeals of laws start with congress and must be passed by congress before the president can sign them into law or veto them.

Maybe the other way around, a previous president can break things (squander the money, get out of alliances, attack somebody) that are really difficult to undo for future presidents in the sense of immediate healing from the effects. Especially money that's gone, that's gone. It won't come back.

Or what about giving pardon to others or himself. That cannot be undone. Or appointment supreme court judges.

In general any POTUS cannot overturn US laws ever or am I mistaken? The question should correct that misconception.

@JoeW and NoDataDumpNoContribution The nuances between a law and executive order may not be fully understood to everyone. The terminology isn't quite right, but the question has merit. Different countries also have different levels of power to their leaders. Also, in some regions, there is no meaningful difference between a law, order, decree, or policy from the government.

@DavidS That is why I asked for clarification on what they mean

@DavidS The question is tagged United States, otherwise there might be hundreds of answers for each country.

Regarding changes in policy: policies that do not work, that have undesired consequences or that are undesirable in the first place should be changed or tossed out. This is the reason that presidents give when they change or institute a policy. The reason may be justified or not, depending on one's point of view. Therefore, it's essentially a political question and in the long run, the voters are supposed to make the decisions. Changes like this are designed into the system; in the long run, the country is supposed to go in the right direction by the will of the people.

That would be the pardon. Pardons cannot be revoked once issued.
Appointment to a federal court as a judge cannot be revoked once approved; however that is not strictly a presidential action; and even then the judge can be impeached. Removing a judge because the the next government doesn't like the appointment is a bad idea; however it is possible.

Judges can be impeached. But you are correct about pardons. Nobody has plumbed the depths of how durable a pardon is.

@Machavity A pardon must be eternal because while a President can pardon, they cannot convict; that is up to the courts, but the double jeopardy clause prohibits another trial.

An impeachment is conducted by congress, not by the President -- it does not count here, does it? Simply "removing" a (federal) judge is not possible, the procedure is the impeachment.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Congress is also the last mover in installing a judge; so it doesn't count in any case. It is listed because it is the next hardest thing of law to undo after a pardon.

"Congress is also the last mover in installing a judge": not so.  First, it is only the Senate, not Congress, and second, after Senate confirmation, the judge receives a commission from the president, which is the document formally appointing the judge to the court.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Generally speaking, the answer is "No". Congress cannot bind future Congresses. Likewise, a sitting President cannot truly bind a future President.
There's two moving parts to understand here
The Administrative State
Congress has, over time, created new agencies under the Executive branch. These agencies sometimes have Cabinet-level positions (such as the Secretary of the Department of Homeland Security) that need Senate approval.
These institutions all report to the President, and all have some authority to write and enforce rules and regulations, per the laws enacted to give them the authority in the first place (i.e. the Environmental Protection Agency cannot issue workplace safety rules or investment regulations). Generally, a President will appoint people to head agencies that agree with their general political views.
All rules issued and enforced this way are subject to the Administrative Procedures Act. It states that new rulemaking must go through a public comment phase and appropriate timelines before becoming enforced. These are not laws, but administrative rules. To that end, Congress may vacate any administrative rules by voting them out. Courts can also overturn rules, especially if they did not follow the APA rules.
A future President will almost certainly make their own appointments so they can shape future rules. An agency may abandon rules their predecessors made, as long as they do so within the APA requirements, and do not violate the rules set forth by Congress for that agency (i.e. the EPA cannot stop enforcing the Clean Air Act, or any other law it has been directed to enforce).
Executive Actions
Executive Actions are usually just directives from a sitting President that direct the Federal Government on what the President wants done. These contain no actual force of law and can be rescinded by any future Executive Action.
A perfect example of this is the Mexico City Policy, which pertains to funding foreign abortion efforts. First created by Ronald Reagan, it has been rescinded by every Democratic president, and reinstated by every Republican president since.

Once exception to the rule that a Congress can't bind a future Congress is that Congress may make multi-year appropriations beyond the current Congressional session to enter into naval defense contracts, because even in 1789, you couldn't build a naval ship in less than two years in many cases. More generally, neither the President nor Congress can unilaterally breach contracts that they enter into on behalf of the United States government (including, e.g., employment contract such as pensions for federal employees, and the national debt).

@ohwilleke why am I not surprised that they made that one special exception for a war-related issue

@Hobbamok Back in 1789, war was the dominant thing that the federal government was expected to do. The federal government dramatically expanded in 1861 and beyond.

@ohwilleke true, and - from a foreign-sociological perspective - that sentiment never really went away

@Hobbamok A navy isn't just for war: the US was paying incredible amounts of money as tribute or ransom to pirates at the time.

Thanks! I didn't know about the APA or the Mexico City Policy- fascinating stuff

@ohwilleke it would be more precise -- especially in the context of this question -- to say "neither the President nor Congress can unilaterally breach contracts that they or their predecessors enter into on behalf of the United States government."  It is a minor point, and the added "or their predecessors" is already implicit, but In this context it seems worthwhile to make it explicit.

@ohwilleke the part about federal employees falling under the 6th amendment was a huge oversight by the Founding Fathers, as two centuries later it made it very hard for the Executive to fire their subordinates, thus effectively creating the “Deep State” where the elected officials can barely control their “employees”.

@JonathanReez this comment makes no sense whatsoever.  What do the rights of accused criminals have to do with the management of federal government employees?

@phoog you’re right, the problematic clause is Article I, Section 10. Unfortunately it didn’t have an exception for government employees.

@JonathanReez that is equally nonsensical.  Article I section 10 limits the powers of states.  As such it has no relevance to federal employees.

@phoog courts have since ruled it de facto applies to the Federal government too.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JonathanReez Federal employees sometimes have 5th Amendment rights. The 6th Amendment pertains to criminal defendants. The difficulty in firing federal employees has very little to do with the Founders and everything to do with the post-Jacksonian statutory establishment of civil service reforms. The "Deep State" as you call it, is a feature and not a bug that was intentionally created by Congress to do what it does and rightly so as it is better policy than the alternative. The "unitary executive" theory has no basis in history is a flimsy misreading of Constitutional language.

@ohwilleke lookup the recent refusal of Federal workers to go back to office despite Biden mandating them to do so. Apple has faced the same conundrum and plainly told everyone to be back in person or be terminated. 90-95% came back (depending on the source), the rest were terminated or quit. Tim Cook has actual power over Apple employees, the US President's power is strongly diminished and subject to the whims of entrenched, unelected bureaucrats.

@JonathanReez Those entrenched , unelected bureaucrats are selected based upon merit, have a long term interest in the success of the institutions for which they work, and owe allegiance to the law that the President is sworn to uphold rather than the individual. Civil service protections are a vital safeguard against politicians with no regard for the rule of law.

@ohwilleke how is refusing to go back to office part of their long term interest in the success of the institutions? Seems like a long term interest in personal gain to me.

As a practical example: invading another country be it for high-minded reasons like regime-change in bringing democracy etc. As easy it might be in theory for a new president to just pull out all forces on day one of his mandate, it never worked out like that.
Italian Philosopher already gave some treaty cancellations as similar enough examples. There are surely more of those, including cancelling the JCOPA with Iran etc. (Which was somewhere like restarting a cold war, although it also briefly turned hot when an Iranian general was killed in a US strike and Iran shot some missiles back at US bases.) Relatedly, the US system/constitution never really resolved if POTUS can single-handedly cancel treaties or not. It's still a grey area. And presidents have done their best to expand the grey area to what kind of agreements they can enter by themselves.

Putting your two examples into clear abstract wording: Any measure that creates hard-to-reverse facts in reality [within the presidential/congressional term (aka before it can be overturned by the next guy)]. Like sure, Biden (somewhat) overturned Trumps removal of train safety regulations, but Palestine, Ohio remains poisoned for centuries.

An incoming president can order an immediate withdrawal from that invaded country, thus overturning the previous president's invasion order. Obviously implementation of either order is going to take time (and cleaning up the diplomatic mess even more). Not even a presidential decree can change the impact of logistical nightmares (and of course the Deep State can simply ignore the president, as happened with Trump's order to pull out of Syria, DoD and State simply ignored the president and kept doing their thing there).

JCOPA wasn't a treaty under US law and therefore isn't a good example of a president unilaterally cancelling a treaty.

@gormadoc: my point with that wasn't the way Trump undone it, but the failed efforts to bring it back thereafter, even if in theory Biden could have just reinstated it. The world had "moved on" in various facts-on-the-ground ways.

We can generally group US Federal things with force of law into three* categories ordered by supremacy:

The Constitution
Laws and statutes enacted by Congress, and treaties ratified by Congress
Executive Orders and other Executive regulations, which can include practical adherence to treaties not ratified by Congress

Each category empowers the categories below it.  For the purpose of the answer, "law" means anything passed in the second category by Congress.  In general, Congress will pass laws that give the Executive Branch the power to do something, such as determine regulation for carbon emissions.  Laws like that will probably specify which Executive agency will write the regulations, but the President has authority over the entire Executive Branch so he is free to tell that agency what regulations to write, as long as they are within the bounds of the law which gives them the power to regulate that thing.  When a new President comes in, he is also free to tell his agencies to execute their regulatory powers in a different way, so long as it is still within the bounds of the law.
So, to directly answer the question, there are no laws enacted through the Constitutional process to pass a law (which includes the President, but is mainly Congress) which a future President can unilaterally overturn.  He may be able to execute the law in a way that obviates it in part or in whole, since the Executive Branch is ultimately the branch responsible for carrying out the intended practical effects of a law.  On the other hand, any regulations enacted by the Executive Branch are subject to change by the Executive Branch at a later date, the only ways to make them permanent are to enshrine them in a law or a constitutional amendment.
* I've not included judicial precedent/review here because it would be confusing and isn't needed for the answer, but it could be argued that it is it's own category

For one topic, Congressional pay, a president's hands are constitutionally tied by the previous administration for the first 2 years.
The 27th Amendment states

No law, varying the compensation for the services of the Senators and Representatives, shall take effect, until an election of Representatives shall have intervened.

House elections occur every two years, so any laws signed by a president that modify Congressional compensation can only take effect at two points: after midterm elections or after the end of the presidential term.

Depending on what falls under the scope of "Presidential Actions" for the purposes of this question, it is going to be difficult to reverse the consequences of Trump's Supreme Court appointments.
Biden's has been vaguely talking about term limits and mandatory retirement, but the system does not currently allow for it.
Likewise, to consider how a country can be affected long term by decisions made by political leaders during one particular administration, consider Brexit.  Something similar, effected in the US system, would be hard to undo (for example:  leaving NAFTA).
In fact, Bush's 2002 withdrawal from the ABM Treaty has been cited by Putin as motivation for his policies (whether that's just a convenient excuse or not is for each to decide).
Decisions taken by the Executive that affect international relations are not always easily reversible.

International treaties are the one thing that comes to mind which may not be easily undoable. Would it not be possible that a treaty binds the parties for a specific minimum time? Of course that wouldn't be enforceable, but still.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't know, in general.  I do know it is increasingly unrealistic for an external actor to expect to get a normal ratified treaty out of the US, let alone a specially binding treaty.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica treaties are typically indefinite, though lately they have included a procedure for a party to withdraw.

The Presidential Medal of Freedom would seem to apply. When asked in 2015 whether Bill Cosby would his medal rescinded following sexual assault allegations, President Barack Obama responded, "We don’t have that mechanism."
There was a bill before Congress the following year that would grant the president that power, but it seems not to have gone anywhere.
Congress could theoretically fix this at a future date, but since you asked about acts that presidents "cannot easily reverse," this would seem to fit the bill for the moment.

If a president does things through executive order, meaning by their signature alone, the next president can reverse it. If Congress signed it into law, probably not, at least not easily. President Trump had to do a lot of things through executive order because Congress was against most of it, so it was easy for Biden to reverse it.
